# Add a virtual column for values greater than

Tags: sql, oracle

Question:
Create a virtual column named SALARY_RANGE in the table EMPLOYEES with the below logic.

If salary is greater than 10000 then value should be displayed as ‘Good’ else the value should be displayed as ‘Average.

My Syntax:

```
alter table EMPLOYEES
add column salary_range varchar
(where salary>10000
then salary_range='Good'
else if salary_range='Average') virtual;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add a virtual column with a case expression for your logic:

```
alter table employees add salary_range varchar2(7)
generated always as (
  case when salary > 10000 then 'Good' else 'Average' end
) virtual;
```

or with the optional bits of [the syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_3001.htm#SQLRF53200) removed, just:

```
alter table employees add salary_range as (
  case when salary > 10000 then 'Good' else 'Average' end
);

Table EMPLOYEES altered.
```

You can specify the size explicitly, but Oracle can work it out from the possible results of the case expression:

```
desc employees

Name           Null?    Type         
-------------- -------- ------------ 
EMPLOYEE_ID    NOT NULL NUMBER(6)    
FIRST_NAME              VARCHAR2(20) 
LAST_NAME      NOT NULL VARCHAR2(25) 
EMAIL          NOT NULL VARCHAR2(25) 
PHONE_NUMBER            VARCHAR2(20) 
HIRE_DATE      NOT NULL DATE         
JOB_ID         NOT NULL VARCHAR2(10) 
SALARY                  NUMBER(8,2)  
COMMISSION_PCT          NUMBER(2,2)  
MANAGER_ID              NUMBER(6)    
DEPARTMENT_ID           NUMBER(4)    
SALARY_RANGE            VARCHAR2(7)
```

And to check the generated values:

```
select employee_id, first_name, last_name, salary, salary_range from employees;

EMPLOYEE_ID FIRST_NAME           LAST_NAME                     SALARY SALARY_
----------- -------------------- ------------------------- ---------- -------
        100 Steven               King                           24000 Good   
        101 Neena                Kochhar                        17000 Good   
        102 Lex                  De Haan                        17000 Good   
        103 Alexander            Hunold                          9000 Average
        104 Bruce                Ernst                           6000 Average
        105 David                Austin                          4800 Average
...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Oracle 11g+, then you can add a virtual column as:

```
alter table EMPLOYEES
    add column salary_range varchar2(32) as (case when salary > 10000
then salary_range = 'Good' else salary_range = 'Average' end) virtual;
```

In Oracle, I think I would typically include `generated always`, so:

```
alter table EMPLOYEES
    add column salary_range varchar2(32) generated always as
       (case when salary > 10000
             then salary_range = 'Good' else salary_range = 'Average'
        end) virtual;
```

In earlier versions, you would need to add a real column and populate it using `update`.